# The footer doesn't take its place

Tags: php, html, django-templates

here is the continuation of my previous question. This is my site home page; with your help(thank you, thank you), I fixed the footer to comes in the bottom of my page but now you can see; the footer doesn't get all of the bottom of the page.
[The home page of the site(header isn't important )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iubaI.png)

When I, for example, go to register page the footer doesn't change its place; see:
[Register page (header is not important again)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azkWU.png)

all of my `footer.html` codes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/footer.css">
<footer class="container py-5  navbar-fixed-bottom food">
  <div class="row" style="color: white ; font-family: Forte; height: 100% ; background-color: #1b1e21">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="d-block mb-2" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Product</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><path d="M14.31 8l5.74 9.94M9.69 8h11.48M7.38 12l5.74-9.94M9.69 16L3.95 6.06M14.31 16H2.83m13.79-4l-5.74 9.94"></path></svg>
      <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">©2019-2020</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>Your turn</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'create_res' %}">Add your resturant</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>See our work</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'show_res' %}">Resturants</a></li>
{#        <li><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'rate' %}">Rate resturants</a></li>#}
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>Resources</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Government</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Gaming</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md">
      <h5>About</h5>
      <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I used CSS just in a few lines:

```css
    footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I hope it fixes.**THANKS**
emergency; please help

Comment: Please show your css as well

Comment: I added CSS;just 3 lines; but I hope it helps.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that this css class is overriding your footer code - navbar-fixed-bottom.

Comment: you mean I shouldn't add class - navbar-fixed-bottom?

Comment: No, I am saying that it might be interfering with your current footer code which means it loads the footer incorrect, either change the class, leave navbar-fixed-bottom out and write other code for footer, there are many options.

Comment: tnx, I will test.do you think just that is the problem?

Comment: I TESTED ANYTHING!It isn't gonna feel better. I don't know why the footer doesn't take its place on my web and when I go to for example; to show page,the footer comes on my divs.